# How to parse a keyword that is also an operator

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse the following code using parsec

```
for x = Int in [1, 2, 3]
    print x + 1
```

The only part of the example that might be hard to understand is `x = Int` which means the variable `x` is defined as an `Int`. Syntactically `Int` here is an expression. It might just as well be replaced with a function call that returns a type.

So far I have been able to parse all the simple literals and operators. My problem now is that in this language `in` is a keyword as well as an operator and types (`Int`) are objects like any other (that can be `in` lists). E.g. the following code is perfectly valid and prints `false`

```
print (Int in [1, 2, 3])
```

So right now my parser parses `for x =` correctly and then it parses `Int in [1, 2, 3]` as ONE expression. How can I make the `for` parser grab the `in` instead of leaving it to the `expression` parser? I have a feeling that parsec has something like that built in, but I have no idea how to find it.

**Edit:** I changed the example to make more sense...

**Edit:** I have this difficulty in various places, the language is very complex. Another example is the `else` operator which returns it's second argument if it's first argument is null:

```
print (if true then (null else "hello") else "world")
# >> hello
print (if true then null else "hello" else "world")
# >> world
```

Comment: I don't understand. `Int in [1, 2, 3]` is expression. What is your problem?

Comment: `Int in [1, 2, 3]` is an expression (in which `in` is is a binary operator) just like `1 + 2` is an expression. Thus the expression parser succeeds. But it should not "eat" `in` as an operator because in this case it belongs to the `for` loop as a keyword.

Comment: You mean that you have two kind of expression. One for binary operators and another for `in` operators?

Comment: It's the same kind of expression. The language has binary "keyword like operators" (`is`, `in`) just as well as operators with conventional operator characters (`+`, `-`, `>>`). It is very similar to python.

Comment: Then I don't understand what is wrong with parsing `Int in [1, 2, 3]` as expression. It is expression according to your grammar.

Comment: Yes, nothing is wrong with that. Only in the case of the `for` loop the `for` parser should take precedence and parse the `in` as part of the `for` construct.

Comment: Simplest way to work around it will be change grammar for `for` construct to `for_keyword ~ variable_name ~ assign_token ~ expr` and then validate that expression is `in` expression. If you don't like this idea you have to post your code, because it hard to tell how to fix code without code itself.

Comment: That is a good approach. I fear that it'll get complicated though, because the `in` expression might well be nested in a tree of operators with higher precedence. I was just hoping this problem had already a standard way of solving, but maybe I'm wrong about it

Comment: You have expressions with precedence higher than `in`?

Comment: since you can freely define your own operators (including keyword operators), that might be possible. I'd have to think if that is the case with the default operators, maybe not. The `else` operator has lower precedence than the in operator...

Comment: @n.m. no this is not about the grammar itself, even though I need it for this specific case. I am looking for a general solution in which an "outer" parser can take precedence over an "inner" parser under certain conditions... if such a thing exists...

Comment: @n.m. if this is not possible and requires changing the language definition, that is fine by me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185967/discussion-between-john-smith-and-talex).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @talex and @n.m. for pointing me where I had to look. This is how I solved this specific problem:

I parameterized the `expression` parser (had to enable `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}`) with a list of "eject" words and equally every relevant parser below it, specifically the `binOperator` parser

```
 expression :: [String] -> MyParser AST 

 binOperator :: [String] -> MyParser AST
```

If one of the "eject"-words is encountered in the position of a binary operator, the `binOperator` parser fails (and with the `chainl1` based parser that reads binary operations), thus leaving the "eject" word (in this case `in`) to the `for` parser to consume. This should work just as well with the `if` parser.

And I simply don't pass the eject words to the `paren` parser so there are no eject words recognized between `(` and `)` (and similar parsers like list).